# Set a Laravel 7 Cookie From API Request

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

i'm having problem setting a cookie or a session through API request , I tried to use the web middleware & tried to move the route to the web folder , nothing really works.
My Route: web.php

```
Route::get('api/add-item-to-cart' ,'CartController@addItem')->name('cart.add');
```

My Controller: CartController@addItem

```
setcookie('name','value');
$CartData['user_id'] = Cookie::get('guest_id');
//Always Returns Null
```

Die and Dump the Cookie::get() returns :

```
array:7 [▼
  "fdsfsda" => null
  "name" => "value"
  "token" => null
  "guest_id" => null
  "XSRF-TOKEN" => "JwqisWA0rMCLnFmBitqK8Va0lXwCMjP7A2Ks2Bi1"
  "uk_fashion_shop_session" => "ngMrvLmPQZ8SrfnonA9pVLFID05OIk1Su0hOIUrZ"
  "io" => null
]
```

So the cookie is actually getting set , but without a value
Notes: The Cookie is getting set , but there is no value assigned to it for some reason but when i use the laravel way , the cookie is not even set
//The Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('guest_id', md5(rand(1,500)))); is not setting anything at all

my session file is as the default

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your cookie is not set. But to be sure that it's strictly laravel issue, maybe missing dependency, specify appriopriate details about your cookie, using for example `response API`.

```php
return response('Hello World')->cookie(
    'name', 'value', $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly
);
```

Be sure, you set expiration date which is greater than current timestamp (it will expire almost instantly otherwise), set domain exactly as your domain (DNS specified) and path, for example global `/` for testing purpouse.

UPDATE
You can also debug cookies in your browser.

In Mozilla **CTRL+SHIFT+I** --> **Data** --> **Cookies**.

And after that, you can see all cookies which are stored by your browser.